# Using xstream's XmlArrayList and FilePersistenceStrategy how can I control the name of the output xml file?

Tags: java, xstream

using xstream's XmlArrayList and FilePersistenceStrategy how can I control the name of the output xml file?

Currently the files are named : int@0.xml

I need to name them with a business understandable file/

link: http://x-stream.github.io/index.html

Code:
PersistenceStrategy strategy = new FilePersistenceStrategy(new File("C:\workingTemp"));

List list = new XmlArrayList(strategy);

list.add(myObj)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if this is the best option, but I think it will work.

Create a custom strategy class `CustomeFilePersistenceStrategy` by extending `FilePersistenceStrategy` and override `getName` method as below:

```
public class CustomeFilePersistenceStrategy extends FilePersistenceStrategy {
     public CustomeFilePersistenceStrategy(File baseDirectory) {
      super(baseDirectory);
     }

    @Override
    protected String getName(final Object key){
        //put desired file naming logic
        return "CustomFile.xml";
    }
}
```

Then the usage could be:

```
 PersistenceStrategy strategy = 
               new CustomeFilePersistenceStrategy(new File("C:\workingTemp"));

 List list = new XmlArrayList(strategy);
```

Which should generate `CustomFile.xml` in the output folder.